# Android - Returning ArrayList to activity from background thread

Tags: java, android, arraylist, thread-safety

I have an activity named `BuildingActivity` that extends `ListActivity`.

In the `onCreate()` method, i'm running 7 database queries in a background thread. In that background thread, I am building an `ArrayList<String>` object from the data returned from the queries.

Now, I want to return that `ArrayList<String>` object back to my `BuildingActivity` thread.

Here's part of the code that Im working on:

```
    public class BuildingActivity extends ListActivity {

        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

        public ArrayList<String> buildings;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_building);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<String> list;

                    DataSource dbSource = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
                    dbSource.open();

                    list = dbSource.getBuildingsList();

                    dbSource.close();

                    //*** NOW HOW DO I PASS list BACK TO onCreate()?
                    //*** I WANT TO MAKE buildings = list.

                }

            }).start();

            if(!buildings.isEmpty()) {
            // do Something.
            // If i do buildings = list in the background thread, 
            // This will always be executed because the background thread can take 
            // some time to return the data. How do i make sure this part of 
            // code is executed only after the data has been returned?
        }
        }   
    }
```

My objective after this is to create a list from this returned list of buildings. And on clicking a building, another activity shall open. How do I get about this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: see the method below....when your list is not null then you can add a condition in the //return your list here block to the UI thread

Comment: isnt buildings = list possible ?? Whats the error ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille it is possible.  But then my `if` statement below the thread will always be executed as the Activity thread wont be waiting for the background thread to complete.

Comment: Just as ρяσѕρєя K hs mentioned use an asyc task instead of the thread. where in the post execute you could call a method that contains the if condition

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille okay I shall try and get back.

Comment: gudluck @AninditKarmakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i make sure this part of code is executed only after the data
>   has been returned?

Instead of using Thread for doing task in background use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which provide `doInBackground` for performing operation in background and `onPostExecute` methods run on UI Thread after completing background task

Comment: Yes. I read about AsyncTask. I even tried that approach by nesting a class that extends AsyncTask in my BuildingActivity. But I could not access the buildings data member of BuildingActivity from the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: @AninditKarmakar : make a inner class of BuildingActivity which extends AsyncTask and declare all members which you want to access in onPostExecute globally. please share  AsyncTask related code to get more help

Answer (score 0):

here use this

```
public void myMethod(){
     Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run(){
            Looper.prepare();
            //Do your data rerieval work here
               Runnable r=new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   //return your list from here                      
               }
            };
            handler.post(r);
            Looper.loop();
         }
    });
    background.start();
 }
```